# Firefox opens multiple empty pages while Selenium test running and test fails to identify elements

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I'm writing a Selenium test script for my website. Firefox opens multiple empty pages while Selenium test running and test fails to identify elements in my script. Im using **47.0.1 firefox** and **selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta3**.

Here is my Main activity.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

// Print the Execution Date
        GetExecutionDate getExDate = new GetExecutionDate();
        getExDate.getExecutionDate();

        MainFlow mainFl = new MainFlow();
        mainFl.mainFlow();
    }

}
```

Here is my `MainFlow.java` file.

```
public class MainFlow {

    public void mainFlow() throws InterruptedException{

        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","D:\\My Work\\Setup\\JAR\\geckodriver.exe");

        // Initialize Firefox Profile
        ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();    
        FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("Myyy");  
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);


        //Puts an Implicit wait, Will wait for 25 seconds before throwing exception
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //Launch Ayubo.lk site
        driver.navigate().to("my site");

        //Maximize the browser
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='navbar-main']/ul/li[5]/a")).click();
        System.out.println("User clicked My Account button");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='navbar-main']/ul/li[5]/ul/li/a")).click();
        System.out.println("User clicked Login button");
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        // Enter User name
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("dd@hh.com");
        System.out.println("User enter username");

        // Enter Password
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("12345");
        System.out.println("User enter password");
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        // Click Login Button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='loginform']/div[8]/button")).click();
        System.out.println("User clicked Login button");
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        // Click Book now Button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='navbar-main']/ul/li[2]/a/span")).click();
        System.out.println("User clicked Book now button");
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        // Click Book hotels button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='navbar-main']/ul/li[2]/ul/li/a")).click();
        System.out.println("User clicked Book Hotels button");

    }

}
```

But, when the script is running it opens up different empty pages and script fails

Comment: Try once by clearing cache using selelium code.

Comment: How am i suppose to do that?

Comment: driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();  you can write this after navigating to the url

Comment: Not working :( `Element is not clickable at point (1012.11669921875, 38.33332824707031). Other element would receive the click:` is the issue I get

Comment: Then try once by giving coordinates of the particular element ant then perform click. this can be done with robot class Robot bot = new Robot(); bot.mouseMove(x, y); bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); x,y are your element coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3185/firefox-browser-launches-blank-page-while-running-tests-via-selenium). This is because of compatibility issue with the browser and Selenium libs. Selenium libs Im using supports Firefox version different firefox versions, and for 12 I have to upgrade your Selenium libs.